# Codeigniter mssql_query fails with 'unable to set query' error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter app that accesses 57 MSSQL databases to generate a monthly report with a click of a button.

When I generate a report, it can access and fetch the data just fine from most of the servers. However, there are some servers that just return error message shown below.

I could generate the `Unable to set query` error message by turning 'db_debug' flag on. Last line is the result from `mssql_get_last_message()`.

```
mssql_query(): Query failed
mssql_query(): Unable to set query
Query error: Changed database context to 'dbsdb'
```

This is the query I use to fetch the data

```
SELECT * FROM   [tblLogin] AS L 
                 LEFT JOIN [tblStation] AS S ON L.[strStation] = S.[strStation] 
                 LEFT JOIN (
                      SELECT [strStation], COUNT(DISTINCT(nRecordId)) as nOrders
                      FROM   [tblOrder]
                      WHERE  [timeOrderDate] >= '2013-12-03' AND
                             [timeOrderDate] <= '2013-12-26'
                      GROUP BY strStation
                 ) AS O ON O.[strStation] = S.[strStation]
WHERE  L.[timeLoginTime] >= '2013-12-03 00:00:00' AND L.[timeLoginTime] <= '2013-12-03 23:59:59'
```

Weird thing is that the query sometimes works if I set the date range to only one day. For example, this query works when date range is '2013-12-26'. However, it doesn't work when date range is '2013-12-03'. When I manually queried the database using query analyzer, I get 172 rows for '2013-12-03', and 126 rows for '2013-12-26'.

These are some phpinfo data that might help.

```
mssql.connect_timeout = Unlimited
mssql.timeout = Unlimited
memory_limit = 2048M
max_execution_time = 0
```

These are the codes I use to fetch data.

```
$sql = "...";
$dbgroup = array(
    'hostname' => ...,
    'username' => ...,
    'password' => ...,
    'database' => 'dbsdb',
    'dbdriver' => 'mssql',
    'db_debug' => true,
    'pconnect' => false,
);
$db = $this->load->database($dbgroup, true);
$result = $db->query($sql)->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this same issue using php and Zendframework 1 at my organization. The inconsistency led us to determine that the issue was not in the code or the server but instead was the result of the database host throttling our service. The issue only occurred when a new ERP using mssql was introduced.

Not sure if this will be the same for you.